# Deleting all values of pandas except a given value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data.

`QoSID               ConnectionID
QosQ_Pr0:EwB        CN05242968
QosQ_Pr0:C2wB       CN05242968
QosQ_Pr0:EnB        CN05242968
....
....
QosQ_Pr1:EwB        CN05242968
QosQ_Pr1:C2wB       CN05242968`

I would like to delete all value of the row "QoSID" but I keep only one given value, let's say the 1st, "QosQ_Pr0:EwB"

I used 
`data = data[~data['QoSID'].isin(['QosQ_Pr0:C2wB','QosQ_Pr0:EnB' ....])]` but since I have different values, I would like something that takes the given value what I want to keep, and delete the rest values

Comment: How is the dataframe supposed to look like in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just filter for the value you wish to keep:

```
data = data[data['QoSID'] == 'QosQ_Pr0:EwB']
```

If there are repeats for this value and you only wish to keep the first:

```
data = data[data['QoSID'] == 'QosQ_Pr0:EwB'].head(1)
```